# Importing @pokusew/pcsclite in Angular2/Electron throws TypeError

Tags: angular, typescript, electron, pcsc

I have an Angular CLI project running within Electron. I am trying to use NFC functionality by importing `@pokusew/pcsclite`in one of my components. I use `import * as pcsclite from "../../node_modules/@pokusew/pcsclite"` to import the library. However, once I call `this.pcsc = pcsclite()` I get the following error in the console:

> TypeError: exists is not a function

And during the build process:

> WARNING in ./~/bindings.js
>
> Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Comment: update the post with screenshot of the error and minimum code. Also have a look at [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking

Answer (score 0):

The `TypeError: exists is not a function` appears to be a bug in the node-bindings module. See: https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-bindings/pull/20

It should be fixed when the new release is available on NPM.

However, going one step further, this fix will still not make the `@pokusew/pcsclite` work when using AngularCLI/Webpack. To make it work in this setup `@pokusew/pcsclite` would need to use `node-loader` instead of `node-bindings` to load the binding file. You can change it locally like this:

Edit "/node_modules/@pokusew/pcsclite/package.json":

```
"dependencies": {
  "bindings": "github:tootallnate/node-bindings#pull/20/head", < Instead of this,
  "node-loader": "^0.6.0", << use this
  "nan": "^2.5.1"
},
```

Then edit "/node_modules/@pokusew/pcsclite/lib/pcsclite.js"

`const pcsclite = require('node-loader!./../build/Release/pcsclite.node');`